# How to popup your own lookup?

Tags: visualforce, lookup

I have a page full of `apex:inputfield` tags.  On one of these inputfields I'd like to popup my own lookup window.  What should my approach be?

It seems that `apex:inputfield` is bound to a data field, but I'd like to retain the existing look and feel of salesforce, yet popup my own VF page.

How do I go about something like that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both Bob Buzzard and Jeff Douglas have excellent blog posts on this very subject.  I have implemented both and each works very well.  I would check these out and they will at least get you started.

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2010/09/visualforce-lookup.html

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

Answer (score 4):

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/ and http://sfdchack.blogspot.in/2013/01/salesforce-custom-lookup-using-apex.html

There are already few blogs on how you can roll your own window .